# Is there a good way to insert random HTML/JS snippets in elm?

Tags: elm

I'd like to embed the following snippet in an elm app I'm writing:

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/jpaugh/2988462.js"></script>
```

I've tried using the `[markdown|..|]` quasi-quoter,

```haskell
header = plainText "blah, blah."
gist = [markdown|
<script src='https://gist.github.com/jpaugh/2988462.js'></script>
|]

main = flow down [header, gist]
```

And that throws an error that *clearly* represents a bug in Elm, and puts all of my content inside a `<noscript>`.

```html
<noscript>
  <p>blah, blah</p>
  <p><script src='https://gist.github.com/jpaugh/2988462.js'></script>
    </p>
</noscript>
```

But is there another way to do this? Using Markdown syntax to insert html snippets seems precarious to me. Is this covered by one of the library functions? And how should I insulate it from Elm's own javascript? (Using an `<iframe>` doesn't seem to help.)

Edit: Here's the error message. This is what shows up onscreen, not the code.

[image: error msg]

Comment: What is the error you're receiving and why are you putting this inside of the markdown?

Comment: I'm using markdown because it's syntax allows arbitrary html snippets to be inserted.

Comment: Ah, after a quick search I see elm is a whole different language. Sorry, I was wondering why you didn't simply insert the tag in directly. Hope you get your answer.

Answer (score 4):

It may be best to take it the other way around: don't use JS/CSS to mess up elm's "domain" and rather embed elm in normal HTML: you can do what you want outside of the elm box and still run your JS outside:

http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/version-0.8.elm#embedding-elm-in-html-and-js

But I think you can achieve the contents from that snippet already in Elm without using any javascript, I'm not sure what is the thing you are trying to achieve in the end.

Answer (score 3):

## Update: No longer possible

---

I did this, because I am evil.

```
script' : List Attribute -> String -> Html
script' attrs s = node "script" attrs [ text s ]
```

based on `Html` and `Html.Attributes` respectively. Example usage:

```
div [] [ script' [] "alert(tremble in fear elm);" ]
```

as such

```
script : List Attribute -> List Html -> Html
script attrs children = node "script" attrs children

scriptSrc : String -> Html
scriptSrc s = script [ type' "text/javascript", src s ] []

scriptRun : String -> Html
scriptRun s = script [ type' "text/javascript" ] [ text s ]
```

Comment: This does not work anymore. Apparently, Elm [deliberately blocks](https://github.com/elm/virtual-dom/blob/4ff4f5a17c7406e2fb66f7c78899d91f7c48646e/src/Elm/Kernel/VirtualDom.js#L279) `<script>` tags from being embedded. See [this demonstration](https://ellie-app.com/4WCf47YcDNKa1).